# Installing PyQt5 Designer on windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, installation, pyqt5

I installed PyQt5 using Windows command window and `pip3 install PyQt5` as described in the [download page](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5), it was installed successfully. but I didn't found PyQt Designer in the Windows Start Menu so I thought I need to install it separately. After searching various forums, I tried adding it using `pip3 install pyqt5-tools` it shows `Successfully installed pyqt5-tools-5.9.0.1.2` but PyQt Designer wasn't installed.

Is there any way to install PyQt Designer?

My Python version:

```
>>> python --version
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a workaround, first I uninstalled `PyQt5` and `pyqt5-tools-5.9.0.1.2`

```
pip3 uninstall PyQt5
pip3 uninstall pyqt5-tools-5.9.0.1.2
```

I went to [this page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.6/), downloaded the `PyQt5-5.6-gpl-Py3.5-Qt5.6.0-x64-2.exe` file and installed it normally.

Comment: 'Installed it normally' seems to suggest that you meant installing it the windows way, which is usually not normal.

Answer (score 2):

On windows 10, with Python3.5, and pyqt5, I installed pyqt5-tools using pip:

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

and the designer was automatically install in the following folder:

```
"Python directory"\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools
```

Comment: Are you using 32bit Windows? I try `pip install pyqt5-tools` and just get `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5-tools (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt5-tools`

Comment: This was for 64 bit windows. I have not tried it on win32.

Comment: I tried with python for 32 and 64 bits but couldn't get installed. `pip show pyqt5-tools` shows it for me but when I try `pip install pyqt5-tools` if says that no candidate satisfies etc etc etc, and nothing is installed.

Comment: On windows, you need to have admin privileges for pip to work properly. Do you? just the command window where you run pip has to have the admin privileges.

Comment: Well, I have admin permission but the cmd wasn't started as Administrator, this may be the case. I just give up on designer and setup everything with layouts.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you!
 Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
 PyQt5==5.11.3
 PyQt5-sip==4.19.13
 pyqt5-tools==5.11.2.1.3

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
pip install pyqt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

Now you'd find the designer in site-packages/pyqt5-tools.

```
Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin
```

Comment: For me, the "designer.exe" was not in the "pyqt5-tools" folder. It was exactly in the "qt5_applciations\Qt\bin" folder. Thanks for this useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, due to updates of the packages or some other reasons, "designer tool" will not be in the default location.

If so, you can find it here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\Qt\bin

Answer (score 1):

try
`pip install PyQt5Designer`  It will then be under  `lib/QtDesigner/designer.exe`

Answer (score 0):

this is might be not much helpful but i just wanted to share, I install pyqt5 using pip with the tools as well and couldn't find PyQt Designer in the Windows Start as well coz I searched "pyqt designer". I could find it when i searched "designer" only.

Answer (score 0):

pip install pyqt5-tools

....\venv\Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin